# How do you rewrite the slope in terms of Pi?

Tags: pi, slope

Peace to all. I am taking a Physics course that is algebra-based and within one of our assignments, we have insert numbers into Excel and generate a number of graphs.  After graphing said data (which was the easy part), we have to answer a series of questions about said graphs.  One of the questions asks "how could this coefficient be written in terms of π?"  I must admit I have no idea of how to do so.  I am not asking for the answer but assistance on how one could obtain it.  The Coefficient of the slope is "0.7854m".

I was given this hint "Rewrite the area formula =2 in terms of the diameter, =/2. Rename 2 as . Rename   as y." It did not make sense to me though.

Edit:  In Excel we have/had to input our own numbers labeling in the following columns "Diameter (m), Diameter^2/D^2 (m^2), Radius (m), Area (m^2)". For this particular question, I had to use data from the "Area (y-axis) Vs D^2 (x-axis)".

> Area #'s are: 0.785398163, 1.767145868, 3.141592654, 4.908738521,
> 7.068583471, 9.621127502
>
> D^2 #'s are 1 2.25, 4, 6.25, 9, 12.25

....after graphing I got "y=0.7854x" and r^2=1.

[image: Area vs D^2]

Comment: Numerically that's close to $\,\pi/4\,$, but the hint can't be understood unless you tell more about the context, and what "*this coefficient*" is.

Comment: @dxiv Peace, I added more information in the question.

Comment: "*Area (y-axis) Vs D^2 (x-axis)*" $\;-\;$ Assuming that means $A/d^2$ then the ratio is indeed $\,\pi/4\,$ since $A=\pi r^2=\pi d^2 / 4\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I added the graph, for visuals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your graph plots the area of a circle vs the diamater squared. If this is the case, then every $x$ is interpreted as a diameter squared, so we get
$$
x = d^2
$$
On the other hand, since the $y$ value is interpreted as the area of a circle, then we get
$$
y =\text{Area} = \pi r^2
$$
Now, since you numerically obtained the line equation $ y=0.7854 x$, this means that the slope is just the fraction $\frac{y}{x}$, or in other words
$$
\frac{y}{x} = 0.7854 \tag{1}
$$
The question you ask yourself now is, can this slope $\frac{y}{x}$ be written in terms of $\pi$? The answer is yes! We can use the formulas from the beginning to get this:
\begin{align}
\frac{y}{x}= \frac{\pi r^2}{d^2} \overset{\color{purple}{d=2r}}{=}\frac{\pi r^2}{(\color{purple}{2r})^2}= \frac{\pi r^2}{4r^2}= \frac{\pi}{4} \tag{2}
\end{align}
So combining equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ you get that your slope can be written in terms of $\pi$ as
$$
0.7854 \approx \frac{\pi}{4}
$$
giving the desired interpretation, which can be verified with a [calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=numerical+approximation+pi%2F4).

Comment: Thank you so much. What topic(s) or areas should I study to learn how to do this?

Comment: The key thing here is not to forget what your variables $x$ and $y$ _mean_. Notice that the answer just pops out once you substitute the formula for area and the diameter squared, but to do this you need to remember what's the _interpretation_ of your data. Don't get lost in the numbers, always remember what you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

The area of the circle is $\,A=\pi r^2\,$, or $\,A=\pi\left(\dfrac{d}{2}\right)^2=\dfrac{\pi}{4}d^2\,$ in terms of its diameter $\,d=2r\,$.

With $\,y=A\,$ and $\,x=d^2\,$ the graph of the area against the square of the diameter is $\,y=\dfrac{\pi}{4}x\,$.

- The equation represents a straight line, so it makes sense to speak of ***the*** slope of the graph (otherwise, for a non-linear graph, the slope would change between different points).
- The slope is $\,\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\pi}{4}\approx 0.7854\,$. Note that the slope has dimension $\,\dfrac{m^2}{m^2}=1\,$ i.e. it is dimensionless, so it is wrong to say that the slope is $\,0.7854 \color{red}{\,\text{m}}\,$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's weird because I understand but at the same time I didn't. Like my mind had to download a program to make it make sense.